# *ngIf does not see my object as a movie object?

Tags: angular

I've hit this problem where it looks like my *ngIf does not see my object as a movie object and I can't see why? maybe there is another problem?

I've tried these 2 methods but it still doesn't work, can u tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm logging and I can see both in log and in my URL that I am getting the the correct movie id, when I click on a movie.

**Movieservice**

```
  public getMovie(id: number): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + id + 
      "? 
    api_key=mykey")
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .map(({id, title}) => <Movie>(this.movie));

  }



getMovie(id: number): Observable<Movie> {
  return this.http.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + id + "?api_key=mykey")
  .map((response: Response) => <Movie>(response.json()));
}
```

**moviedetail component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }
```

**my html file with the *ngIf**

```
<div class="container">
<div *ngIf="movie">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h1>Movie:</h1>
            <b>Title:</b> {{movie.title}}<br>
            <button (click)="gotoMovies()">Back</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where abouts in the component are you setting `this.movie`?

Comment: You're calling the service, bu don't do anything with the returned observable. In particular, you never initialize `this.movie`, which is what *ngIf is testing.

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't make any sense, BTW. And I really wonder why you keep using the deprecated Http service instead of the documented HttpClient service: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: What is `*ngIf="movie"` movie here ? How are you setting this value? Are you using httpclient in angular 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't assigned value to `this.movie`, also `Observable` are lazy in nature. They just seat as function when you initialize them, they will only get executed when you subscribe to it.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(
    movie => this.movie = movie
  );
}
```